# How to keep all added markings/notes in pdf when using includegraphics?

Tags: graphics, pdf, includegraphics

The following is the is the scenario.  I write the HW in latex, compile to PDF, upload to school website. Teacher grades the PDF adding marks and notes in red directly to the PDF (I assume they use some tool to do this, or may be use PDF own notes tools).

I download the graded PDF file. I like to include it to my main course document again, using `\includegraphics`. But the markings in red are all lost and do not show in the final PDF document.

I can see the red marking on the screen when I open the graded PDF on its own using adobe PDF read. I also can print the graded PDF and the printed pages show the red markings.

It is only when I include the graded PDF, they do not show again the final PDF.

Here is MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=0.8\pagewidth,page=1]{p}

\end{document}
```

the file `p.pdf` used above is one graded page to show the problem. Please find it here [p.pdf](https://www.12000.org/tmp/060921/p.pdf)  (safe link, it is my own web page)

Any idea why this happens and how to fix it?

Do I need to do something to the graded pdf itself before including again in Latex so that the added notes and marking show up?

One option I could do is this, which works: Print all the pages of the graded PDF. Then scan them all again using the scanner to new PDF file. Now the resulting PDF will have these marking embedded in them as images, and they will show up if I include the scanned version of the PDF in my main document.

But this is too much work, and the quality of the scanned PDF is not as good as the original.

Any suggestions what to do?  I use `lualatex` to compile Latex if this makes any difference.

**Update**
I tried the [flare](https://github.com/AndreasMatthias/Flare) package  but it does not show the markings. Here is what I tried

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{flare}
%\usepackage{graphicx}% it seems flare loads graphicx automatically

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[scale=0.9,page=1]{p}
\end{document}
```

And now

```
(base) >lualatex foo.tex
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./foo.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 2


 L3 programming layer <2020-12-07> xparse <2020-03-03> (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo)) (/home/me/texmf/tex/latex/flare/flare.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def))) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def))) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)) (./foo.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))


Module Flare Warning: Annotation of type 'Widget' not supported. on input line 8
Module Flare Warning: Annotation of type 'Ink' not supported. on input line 8
Module Flare Warning: Annotation of type 'Ink' not supported. on input line 8
Module Flare Warning: Annotation of type 'Ink' not supported. on input line 8

Overfull \hbox (180.86038pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 8--9
[][]
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
Overfull \vbox (166.9664pt too high) has occurred while \output is active [2<./p.pdf>]
 (./foo.aux))
(see the transcript file for additional information)
 406 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 48 glue_spec, 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 1:2,2:33,3:8,4:2,5:22,6:2,7:29,9:30
</usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman12-regular.otf>
Output written on foo.pdf (2 pages, 25355 bytes).
Transcript written on foo.log.
(base) >
```

It looks like the annotations added to the PDF are not support by flare package at this time. The generated PDF files do not show the annotation/markings in the `p.pdf` file.

I added a discussion at github on this to the author of flare package, and put a link to this post also.

Comment: Annotations are stripped when a graphic is included. The newpax package allows to reinsert links, and the project works on markup annotations  https://github.com/AndreasMatthias/Flare

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks. I tried it now, but it does not work. I'll post detailed in my question now.

Comment: Better add an issue to the github. This a quite new project.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, I just did, under discussion in the flare link, and put a link there to this question also. Thanks.

Comment: I added support for `/Ink` annotations a few days ago but missed to push a new release. Please download the latest release from github again. `/Widget` annotations are _not_ supported yet, but I'm working on it.

Comment: I imported the PDF to a graphics editor (GIMP) then exported it to PDF again and the marks showed up using \includegraphics.  BTW, you want \paperwidth or \textwidth instead of \pagewidth.

Comment: @JohnKormylo thanks for the hint. I just installed GIMP on windows and I tried what you said. Indeed it works. But there is a problem. The quality of the exported PDF is not good.  it does not seem to be vector graphics. When I zoom in the pages of the exported PDF, it becomes blarred and fuzzy, like it is a png image. Properties of exported PDF shows no fonts in it (under File->Properties->Fonts, using adobe PDF reader).  I think GIMP just converted the pdf pages to images, then exported these to PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default conversion for PDF->GIMP is 100 DPI which is inadequate, but can easily be modified (600 DPI).  The following image was obtained by deleting everything that wasn't red.  (Tools->Selection Tools->Select by Color, Select->Invert, Edit->Clear).

[image: marks]

The background is transparent, so you can overlap the two images.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\rlap{\includegraphics[page=1]{p.pdf}}%
\includegraphics{p.png}

\end{document}
```