# Ipad-Annotation on pdf is deleted when using input command

Tags: input

When I use the command input(file.pdf), the annotation on the pdf gets deleted. Is there a way to keep the annotations.

P.S. I cannot upload a annotated pdf file to test it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by input on a PDF file? `\includegraphics`? It is well known that any extra meta data such as form data or annotations are removed when included using `\includegraphics`.

Comment: You might not be able to update an annotated PDF, but you can show how as to how you "input"

Comment: Also related/duplicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/600664/how-to-keep-all-added-markings-notes-in-pdf-when-using-includegraphics, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194958/includepdf-combined-pdf-highlights-missing